# How to determine the current state of a HTML Button

Tags: javascript, button

From plain javascript, how can I tell if a `<button>` is currently pressed or not?

It isn't sufficient to use mouse events, because the button could be pressed due to an alternate input method, such as a key press, or maybe even some other accessibility method that somebody invents in the future (tablets come to mind).

But in searching the properties and attributes of the `button` element, I don't see anything showing the buttons current state.

Comment: What do you want to do with this information?

Comment: One day we'll all have *I Dream of Jeannie* blink-control. Buttons will be obsolete.

Comment: @FelixKling Feed it to my cat!  Just kidding, I'm actually trying to find a reliable way of catching state changes; since mouse events aren't sufficient I figure if I can get the button's actual state at various intervals if will be better than nothing.

Comment: @JaredFarrish We will still have the same problem if I don't have a reliable way to tell if the eyes are open or closed... ;-)

Comment: The onclick event won't work for you?

Comment: @Cheruvian That only tells me when the button has been pressed and then released.  In some cases I want to do something separate when the button has been pressed but not yet released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit late, but I stumbled over the same question so here I am. Maybe this still can be helpful to others. According to the [HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) the button element doesn't have a state. If a button is currently pressed or not is a matter of CSS. The [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) defines that the :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. So the questions boils down to how to get that class with javascript. This can be done with

```
this == document.activeElement
```

where this is the button. The statement is true if the button is active.

It actually makes sense that a button, other than a checkbox, doesn't keep a state.

Answer (score 1):

Combine event handlers. Demo here: http://jsbin.com/horeq/2/edit

HTML

```
<button id="a">Button</button>


<pre id="output"></pre>
```

jQuery

```
var output = $('#output'),
    btn    = $('button#a');

var active;

btn.on('mousedown keydown', function(data) {
  active = 'on';
  output.html(active);
})
btn.on('mouseup keyup', function(data) {
  active = 'off';
  output.html(active);
})
```

JS (Could be more efficient)

```
var output = document.getElementById('output'),
    btn    = document.getElementById('a');


var active;

btn.addEventListener('keydown', function(data) {
  active = 'on';
  output.innerHTML = active;
});

btn.addEventListener('keyup', function(data) {
  active = 'off';
  output.innerHTML = active;
});

btn.addEventListener('mousedown', function(data) {
  active = 'on';
  output.innerHTML = active;
});

btn.addEventListener('mouseup', function(data) {
  active = 'off';
  output.innerHTML = active;
});
```

Comment: The OP specified plain Javascript, not jQuery.

Comment: That demo is throwing errors at me, but from what I can tell, how does it know that the keydown is actually pressing the key?  for instance, in my own code i have tried doing a similar thing, but i can press for example the character 'a' key and it thinks I am pressing the button, even though the button state is not actually changing.

Comment: @Michael It was throwing errors cause I was live editing it. Here's the final: http://jsbin.com/horeq/1/edit?js,output

Comment: @Michael good point you can add some check though. `if ( event.keyCode  == whatever key code )` etc

Comment: @elzi is there some standard which states what key codes can be used? The space bar seems to be the common one, but will this be universally true?

Answer (score -1):

Add "onclick"-tag to your code.

```
<input type="button" name="button" value="button" onclick="myfunction()">
```

Now device run javascript-function, if button are clicked!